# How can I access data property as variable in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I made a function that uncheck all elements when the button is pressed.
Whether it is selected or not is judged by the value of "isActive" property of each data.

```
  data : {
    genres : [
      { "id" : "1", "name" : "Apple",  "isActive" : true },
      { "id" : "2", "name" : "Banana", "isActive" : true },
      { "id" : "3", "name" : "Peach",  "isActive" : true }
    ],
    departments : [
      { "id" : "1", "name" : "Apple",  "isActive" : true },
      { "id" : "2", "name" : "Banana", "isActive" : true },
      { "id" : "3", "name" : "Peach",  "isActive" : true }
    ]
  }
```

The code for uncheck all is like this.

```
  methods : {
    clearAllActiveClasses(){
      this.genres.forEach(function(item){
        item.isActive = false;
      });

      this.departments.forEach(function(item){
        item.isActive = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

As you can see, the logic is completely same.
The logic will not change in the future. Maybe.

So, in order to make these processes common,
I wrote the following description.

```
  methods : {
    clearAllActiveClasses(){
      let itemGroups = ['genres', 'departments'];

      for(let itemGroup in itemGroups){
        let items = this[itemGroup];

        items.forEach(function(item){
          item.isActive = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

But this code did not work.

How can I make the process common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement iterates over all enumerable properties of an **object**. You need to use the [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement here instead, as it creates a loop iterating over iterable objects like `genres` & `departments` [`array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) in this case:

```
for (let itemGroup of itemGroups) {
  let items = this[itemGroup];
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.isActive = false;
  });
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/5u4xbLjp/)

Comment: Nice!!! I forgot I can not use for in statement in this case. Also it works forEach method as same as for of statement. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can also keep the active state in a common object using a prefix + id as key

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    actives:{},
    genres: [{id:"1",name:"Apple"},{id:"2",name:"Banana"},{id:"3",name:"Peach"}],
    departments:[{id:"1",name:"Apple"},{id:"2",name:"Banana"},{id:"3",name:"Peach"}]
  },
  mounted() {},
  methods: {
    clear() {
      this.actives = {};
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <button @click="clear">CLEAR</button>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Genres
      <input type="checkbox" v-for="gen in genres" :key="`gen-${gen.id}`" v-model="actives[`gen-${gen.id}`]" />
    </li>
    <li>
      Departments
      <input type="checkbox" v-for="dep in departments" :key="`dep-${dep.id}`" v-model="actives[`dep-${dep.id}`]" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you show me another way. I will try it next time.